# Callout accessory without accessory button

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, accessoryview

Is it possible to make a call out accessory view in mapview without an accessory button in it. I am loading a mapview. In some cases, on tapping the pin, I need to show the accessory view, but without an accessory button to tap. Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the `viewForAnnotation` delegate? Using this delegate you can create a custom view for when the pin is tapped.

In here you can do something like this:

```
MKPinAnnotationView *aView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"myPinView"];
aView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
```

If you don't set `rightCalloutAccessoryView` then there will be no accessory button.

Hope this gets you on the right track.